# Can't figure out how to get a background image into my <div> working right

Tags: html, css, web

I'm just learning the basics now. I'm following the Udemy course and the images do not display at all.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>CSS Basics</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style>
            #main {
                width:800px;
                height:1000;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                background-color: #82b3ae;
                padding:20;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                color: green;
                font-size: 50;
            }
            #jumbotron {
                background-image: url('../assets/banner.jpg'); 
                height: 200px;
                width: 800px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="jumbotron">
                 <h1>Neil Harper's Website</h1>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eros elit recteque ex pri, mei iusto oratio te. Duo equidem dolorum antiopam ea. Munere electram suavitate has an. An mei ornatus sensibus eleifend. Vero tritani pro id.</p>
            <p>Ut quo esse porro honestatis, vis ad nisl vidit, id assum voluptaria his. Eos ei tibique vituperata, ridens mentitum persequeris mei in. Habeo doctus partiendo eu nam, dicant appetere vim ex, quo et esse regione. Pri habeo soleat commune cu.
                Ei possit prompta commune vim, cu latine nostrum vix.</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is the image located relative to your html file? If you using firefox you can use firebug to check if the image is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `background-size: 100%;` to `#jumbotron`

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work.
But your background position is not set.

Here is a little jsfiddle for demonstration
https://jsfiddle.net/a1gqsw24/

```
#main {
                width:800px;
                height:1000;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                background-color: #82b3ae;
                padding:20;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                color: green;
                font-size: 50;
            }
            #jumbotron {
        background:url('http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; 
                height: 200px;
                width: 800px;
            }
```

And a really good resource to learn HTML, CSS, JS or PHP is this Website.
http://www.w3schools.com

Maybe you should start there. Have fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

The image file is probably not linked properly.

If the `banner.jpg` file is in the **same directory** as your html, then use the follwing file path:

```
background-image: url('/banner.jpg');
```

If it's **one level above** your html directory, then use the following:

```
background-image: url('../banner.jpg');
```

If it's **one level above** your html directory and **inside a folder**, say `assets`, then use the following:

```
background-image: url('../assets/banner.jpg');
```

(You get the drift)

`../` basically means one folder up (same concept as using the `BACK` button in Windows) if you're navigating through your files and folders.